# Firebase LinkWithCredentialAsync Not Actually Firing Auth State Listener

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-authentication

In the registration of my Xamarin Android app, I sign the user in anonymously in order to hit the database. After all of the inputs are validated, I use `LinkWithCredentialAsync` to create / combine the actual user account with the anonymous one. For some reason Firebase is not notifying my listener after the call is complete, even though the logs suggest that it is. Why isn't Firebase actually notifying the listener that a change has occurred?

LOGS:

```
01-30 10:27:41.221 D/AuthState( 5631): Signing in anonymously.
01-30 10:27:41.450 D/AuthStateListener( 5631): Auth state was changed.
01-30 10:27:41.451 D/Mono    ( 5631): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Firebase.Database[0x7f8bffefb900] -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks[0x7f8bffefc000]: 4
01-30 10:27:41.457 D/AuthState( 5631): AuthCallback function called.
01-30 10:27:43.989 D/FirebaseAuth( 5631): Notifying id token listeners about user ( 8zM08FI8PNRcWW7Zdt7QGQvkM173 ).
01-30 10:27:43.989 D/FirebaseAuth( 5631): Notifying auth state listeners about user ( 8zM08FI8PNRcWW7Zdt7QGQvkM173 ).
01-30 10:27:43.989 D/FirebaseApp( 5631): Notifying auth state listeners.
01-30 10:27:43.989 D/FirebaseApp( 5631): Notified 1 auth state listeners.
01-30 10:27:43.989 D/AuthStateListener( 5631): Auth state was changed.
01-30 10:27:43.991 D/AuthState( 5631): AuthCallback function called.
01-30 10:27:43.996 D/Mono    ( 5631): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
01-30 10:27:43.996 D/Mono    ( 5631): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_boolean_method'.
01-30 10:27:43.996 D/Mono    ( 5631): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_boolean_method'.
01-30 10:27:43.996 D/Mono    ( 5631): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_boolean_method'.
01-30 10:27:45.316 D/Mono    ( 5631): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Firebase.Common[0x7f8bffefb700] -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement[0x7f8bffefbf00]: 2
01-30 10:27:45.321 D/AuthState( 5631): Linking anonymous account with credentials.
01-30 10:27:46.344 D/FirebaseAuth( 5631): Notifying id token listeners about user ( 8zM08FI8PNRcWW7Zdt7QGQvkM173 ).
01-30 10:27:46.346 D/FirebaseApp( 5631): Notifying auth state listeners.
01-30 10:27:46.346 D/FirebaseApp( 5631): Notified 1 auth state listeners.
```

The following code has been reduced, but should give a good idea of how I use it.

AuthStateListener:

```
public class AuthStateListener : Java.Lang.Object, FirebaseAuth.IAuthStateListener
    {
        Action<FirebaseUser> Callback;

        public AuthStateListener(Action<FirebaseUser> oAction)
        {
            this.Callback = oAction;
        }

        public void OnAuthStateChanged(FirebaseAuth auth)
        {
            Log.Debug("AuthStateListener", "Auth state was changed.");
            Callback.Invoke(auth.CurrentUser);
        }
    }
```

AuthStateListener Init:

```
AuthStateListener oListener = new AuthStateListener(AuthCallback);
oAuth.AddAuthStateListener(oListener);

if (FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser == null)
{
    SignInAnon();
}
```

SignInAnon:

```
public async void SignInAnon()
        {
            try
            {
                Log.Debug("AuthState", "Signing in anonymously.");
                await oAuth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync();
            }
            catch
            {
                oDialogHelper.ShowDialog("There was an error. Please try again.");
            }

        }
```

LinkWithCreds:

```
public void LinkWithAnonymous()
        {
            try
            {
                AuthCredential oCred = EmailAuthProvider.GetCredential(txtEmail.Text, txtPasswordConfirm.Text);
                Log.Debug("AuthState", "Linking anonymous account with credentials.");
                oAuth.CurrentUser.LinkWithCredentialAsync(oCred);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Something went wrong (email already used, username in use, etc...)

            }
        }
```

AuthCallback:

```
public void AuthCallback(FirebaseUser oUser)
        {
            Log.Debug("AuthState", "AuthCallback function called.");
            //do something
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is an issue / change in the Xamarin.Firebase.Auth package. I noticed the code stopped working after I updated the NuGet package.

Without changing any code, I reverted back to version 42.1021.1 and eveything works as expected. I suggest that anyone who runs into issues with authentication downgrade to the previous version.

I have started a new issue on the Xamarin Components GitHub that can be found here: https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/issues/294